# Electron + Vite + Sequelize

Tags: vue.js, electron, sequelize.js, vite

Stack:
Electron + vite + vue

I have the issue with sequelize framework. My model looks like:

```
Operation.init({
  itemId: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  },
  startDate: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
  },
  endDate: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
  },
  code: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  }
}, {
  sequelize, 
  modelName: 'Operation',
  timestamps: false
})
```

When I trying to create Operation object in renderer process than I can see error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: moment.isMoment is not a function
    at DATE2._stringify (data-types.js:472:17)
    at DATE2.stringify (data-types.js:24:19)
    at DATE2.bindParam (data-types.js:32:35)
    at MSSQLQueryGenerator.format (query-generator.js:1147:29)
    at MSSQLQueryGenerator.insertQuery (query-generator.js:193:30)
    at MSSqlQueryInterface.insert (query-interface.js:790:37)
    at OperationVisualControl.save (model.js:4154:73)
    at async OperationVisualControl.create (model.js:2305:12)
```

vite.config.ts

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import Vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import VueDevTools from 'vite-plugin-vue-devtools'
import Vuetify, { transformAssetUrls } from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import VueRouter from 'unplugin-vue-router/vite'
import Layouts from 'vite-plugin-vue-meta-layouts'
import { VueRouterAutoImports } from 'unplugin-vue-router'
import Modify from '@kingyue/rollup-plugin-modify'
import * as mdicons from '@mdi/js'
import Electron from 'vite-plugin-electron'
import { notBundle } from 'vite-plugin-electron/plugin'
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills'

const mdi: Record<string, string> = {}
Object.keys(mdicons).forEach((key) => {
  const value = (mdicons as Record<string, string>)[key]
  mdi[
    key.replace(
      /[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z0-9]/g,
      ($, ofs) => (ofs ? '-' : '') + $.toLowerCase()
    )
  ] = value
})

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build: { target: 'esnext', chunkSizeWarningLimit: 5000 },
  server: {
    port: 3000
  },
  plugins: [
    nodePolyfills(),
    Modify({
      exclude: ['node_modules/**'],
      find: /\b(?<![/\w])(mdi-[\w-]+)\b(?!\.)/,
      replace: (match: string) => {
        if (mdi[match]) {
          return mdi[match]
        } else {
          console.warn('[plugin-modify] No matched svg icon for ' + match)
          return match
        }
      },
      sourcemap: false,
    }),
    VueDevTools(),
    VueRouter({ importMode: 'sync', dts: './src/typed-router.d.ts' }),
    Vue({ template: { transformAssetUrls } }),
    Layouts(),
    Vuetify({ autoImport: true }),
    Components({ dts: './src/components.d.ts', types: [] }),
    AutoImport({
      imports: [
        'vue',
        'pinia',
        VueRouterAutoImports,
        {
          vuetify: [
            'useTheme',
            'useRtl',
            'useLocale',
            'useDisplay',
            'useLayout',
          ],
        },
      ],
      dts: 'src/auto-imports.d.ts',
      dirs: ['src/stores'],
    }),
    Electron([
      {
        entry: 'electron/main.ts',
        vite: {
          plugins: [notBundle(/* NotBundleOptions */)],
        },
      }
    ]),
  ],
  css: {
    devSourcemap: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    },
  }
})
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.node.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "include": ["vite.config.*", "electron/**/*",],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "types": [],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build && electron-builder",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "typecheck": "vue-tsc --noEmit -p tsconfig.vitest.json --composite false",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs,.ts,.tsx,.cts,.mts --fix --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "format": "prettier --write src/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@electron/remote": "^2.0.10",
    "@mdi/js": "^7.3.67",
    "@vueuse/core": "^10.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "pinia-plugin-persistedstate": "^3.2.0",
    "prompt-sync": "^4.2.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.37.1",
    "tedious": "^16.6.1",
    "vite-plugin-commonjs": "^0.10.1",
    "vite-plugin-commonjs-externals": "^0.1.4",
    "vue": "^3.3.8",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5",
    "vuetify": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@kingyue/rollup-plugin-modify": "^4.1.0",
    "@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs": "^1.0.3",
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.5.1",
    "@types/jsdom": "^21.1.5",
    "@types/node": "^20.10.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.4.1",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^8.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^12.0.0",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.4.0",
    "electron": "^27.0.4",
    "electron-builder": "^24.6.4",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.18.1",
    "jsdom": "^22.1.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "unplugin-auto-import": "^0.16.7",
    "unplugin-vue-components": "^0.25.2",
    "unplugin-vue-router": "^0.7.0",
    "vite": "^4.5.0",
    "vite-plugin-electron": "^0.15.4",
    "vite-plugin-node-polyfills": "^0.19.0",
    "vite-plugin-vue-devtools": "1.0.0-rc.5",
    "vite-plugin-vue-meta-layouts": "^0.3.1",
    "vite-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.22"
  }
```

I tried multiple vite.config options but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved this issue. I added to vite.config.ts:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    'moment': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/moment/moment.js'),
    "buffer": path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/buffer')
  },
}
```